# Close all Bootstrap Tabs, until I hover one

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have all tabs closed when I arrive on the page. Then, they should be activated on hover. Here's what I've done so far. I think I've done the hover part well, but I can't find how to close my tabs by default. Apparently removing the .active in HTML doesn't work.

```
<!-- TABS -->
<div class="col-xs-3 hidden-xs">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="side-nav">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="full-width active">
                    <a href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TAB1</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="full-width">
                    <a href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TAB2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- TAB CONTENT -->
<div class="tab-content col-xs-9">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane row active" id="tab1">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            TAB CONTENT 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane row active" id="tab2">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            TAB CONTENT 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my script

```
$('.nav-tabs > li > a').hover(function() {
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I think you just have to remove the active class on your tab contents as you said.*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/bXCz8Y7ZOh

**HTML** :

```
<!-- TAB CONTENT -->
<div class="tab-content col-xs-9">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane row" id="tab1">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            TAB CONTENT 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane row" id="tab2">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            TAB CONTENT 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### Update with extanded javascripts: Over and Leave Toggle...

*I think there should have better solutions than this one but it's working...*

**JS**:

```
$('.nav-tabs > li > a').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).tab('show');
});
$('.nav-tabs > li > a').on('mouseleave', function() {
    // remove active class on the tab panel
    $($(this).attr('href')).removeClass('active');
    // remove active class on the tab tab
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
});
```

**Bootply**:  http://www.bootply.com/vTXnT8VckW

Comment: It worked indeed. Now I'm having another issue : I can't hide tab content when hover stops. The last hovered tab remains on screen.